# Unable to install grub2

Tags: grub2

Using a USB thumb drive to install all is well until near the end there is a message:
 The 'grub-efi-amd64 signed' package failed to install in /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader the installed system will not boot.

Then came the message:
installer crashed

We're sorry ........

My pc has a ssd drive plus two hard drives. Win 10 is on the ssd and on the hdds besides data files there are various other partitions including Linux Mint. This is a new pc so my previous grub is not on this pc. If I can install ubuntu to one of the available partitions it should install grub.

I have tried installing ubuntu 18.04 in sda4 and sdb8[][1] several times. Each time I selected a different partition upon which to have the grub boot loader installed. Each time the installer installed most files, but when it got to installing grub I got the error message noted above.

Would the problem be that I am not using the correct partition for the grub boot loader?  Or what?

[My PC partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFVYV.png)

Comment: You are showing RAID, but three unique drives. Some Windows systems seem to want to use the RAID driver even if not RAID in use. Ubuntu requires AHCI not RAID when using desktop installer. If true RAID, you need to use server installer and then add desktop of choice. If converting to AHCI, be sure to install AHCI drivers into Windows first. Grub in UEFI mode does not use your selection of drive, it finds first ESP and installs boot files into that.

Answer (score 0):

By changing disk 2 to GPT and creating a small partition as EFI system Which I used as location for grub boot loader the installation of usuntu was completed.